# AngularJS Valdiation not working with People Picker directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, sharepoint

I am using the following directive so I can have a SharePoint client side people picker in my form:

https://github.com/jasonvenema/sharepoint-angular-peoplepicker

However, using this causes my form validation to fail in that my button never comes out of a disabled state. If I remove the field, validation works, but I need the field.

Here is my button:

```
<button type="button" data-ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" data-ng-click="save()" class="btn btn-default form-control">SAVE ONLY</button>
```

Here is my directive in use:

```
<sp-people-picker name="CC" id="CC" ng-model="vm.cc" min-entries="1" max-entries="20" allow-duplicates="false" show-login="false" show-title="true" min-characters="2" app-web-url="$scope.spAppWebUrl" />
```

Any clues why this field, controlled by a directive, is causing validation to fail in that my button never becomes "enabled"? Please note that the people-picker is not required. It is as if Angular can't "see" the field to test its validation.

**UPDATE:** If I set the field to ng-required="false" my button will enable... unless I remove the values from the people picker, in which cause it goes back to disabled, even though this field is not required!

Comment: try to inspect dom , you should have class on element something like ng-invalid-{anything} it can help us to detect which validator is invaliditing form.

Comment: It appears to be setting it to required. Is there a way to reset the field? <div class="cam-peoplepicker-input ng-isolate-scope ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" id="CC" name="CC" ng-model="vm.cc" ng-required="false" app-web-url="$scope.spAppWebUrl" min-characters="2" show-title="true" show-login="false" allow-duplicates="false" max-entries="20" min-entries="1">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved, as onclick for removal, I am now resetting the model to nothing. Note that since it is an array, the format is as follows:

```
$scope.vm.cc = [];
```